# How to set the timestamp to a header in request and response in nginx?

Tags: http, nginx, httprequest, reverse-proxy

In my use case I would like to set the current timestamp in the request and response in nginx. I want to calculate the time taken by the upstream server. So when the request arrives at the nginx server I would like to set current timestamp as a header and then when the response comes from upstream I would like to another header with the timestamp that time. I will make sure the upstream server adds the request timestamp to response.

Here is my nginx config,

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    client_max_body_size 500M;
    #timeouts
    proxy_connect_timeout       600;
    proxy_send_timeout          600;
    proxy_read_timeout          1m;
    send_timeout                600;
    upstream backend {
      server abcd.com:443;
      keepalive 64;
    }
    #
    # The default server
    #
    server {
      listen   80;
      server_name  http_server;
      error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
      location /products {
            rewrite ^/products/(.*) /$1/$2 break;
            proxy_pass https://backend;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   Host   $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy true;
            real_ip_header     X-Forwarded-For;
            real_ip_recursive  on;
          }
        # redirect not found pages to the static page /404.html
        error_page  404  /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}
```

Could some one help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$time_iso8601` variable which is both machine- & human-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer which answers the question, but which can add some value.

There are several variables available which are listed here http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html

A big subset of them refers to things related to the upstream server, like `$upstream_connect_time`, `$upstream_first_byte_time`, `$upstream_header_time` and so on. These will give you much more insights as you would get by just calculating the difference between "in" and "out". Yet it is not clear to me which `$upstream_*` variable or group of variables would get you the total time of interaction with the upstream server, maybe someone else could post that information.

You can create custom log formats which add the values of these variables into the log files, or possibly add them to the response header.